# AWS ELB OperationNotPermitted when calling the ModifyRule operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-elb

I am trying to do a blue green deployment through a python script, however when ever I run the following piece of code

```
modifyOnBeta = elb_client.modify_rule(
    RuleArn=betarulearn,
    Actions=[
        {
            'Type': 'forward',
            'TargetGroupArn': live_target_group
        }
    ]
)
```

I get the following error

```
botocore.errorfactory.OperationNotPermittedException: An error occurred (OperationNotPermitted) when calling the ModifyRule operation: Default rule 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:listener-rule/app/some-alb/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX' cannot be modified
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. At the top of the [modify-rule doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-rule.html) I found this statement.

> To modify the actions for the default rule, use ModifyListener.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-listener.html

Instead of

```
modifyOnBeta = elb_client.modify_rule(
    RuleArn=betarulearn,
    Actions=[
        {
            'Type': 'forward',
            'TargetGroupArn': live_target_group
        }
    ]
)
```

Use

```
modifyOnBeta = elb_client.modify_listener(
    ListenerArn='string',
    DefaultActions=[
        {
            'Type': 'forward',
            'TargetGroupArn': live_target_group
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).